# Error executing API while fetching folder list

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am creating logicapp to retrieve attachment from Email and copy it to SFTP folder. While Setting up connection to SFTP folder, when I try to select a folder then I get error as in the screenshot

[logic app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z6jE.jpg)

Another user in my company can connect to the SFTP folder using filezilla. However, I am getting an error even with FileZilla. We have confirmed that whitelist of IPs is not enabled and ports are no blocked anywhere.

Any idea how to trouble-shoot this issue? Thanks in advance

harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the api-connection for the SFTP server, have you tried with 'Disable SSH Host Key Validation' turned on? If not try it. You can update the api-connection from the Azure portal.